# Sql server transformar uma coluna em diversas linhas

Tags: sql, sql-server, cursor

Bom dia

Eu tenho uma tabela chamada livros que possui 3 campos, Codigo, Nome e Capitulos
Exemplo de conteudo:

```
32  - Jonas  - 4
```

eu preciso que após o select me retorne o seguinte resultado

```
Codigo e Capitulo 
32       1
32       2
32       3
32       4
```

Me falaram para usar cursor, mas não estou conseguindo

Comment: mostre só mais algum exemplo de dados. Pelo que me parece, não é preciso fazer nada ao campo Nome?

Comment: Realmente não precisa fazer nada com o campo nome, o que vai definir o numero de linhas é a quantidade de capítulos como no exemplo 4 
poderia dar como exemplo o livro 

19 - Salmos - 150 Capitulos ai repetiria o código 19 por 150 vezes indo do capitulo 1 ao 150

Comment: Adicione na pergunta o código que você já fez usando o cursor.

Comment: O Código que eu fiz, está completamente errado, por isto que não o adicionei,

Comment: Você vai fazer uma função com isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não precisa um cursor. Uma possível solução pode ser a seguinte:

```
CREATE TABLE #Livros
(
    Codigo        INT,
    Nome          NVARCHAR(25),
    Capitulos     INT,
)

INSERT INTO #Livros(Codigo, Nome, Capitulos)VALUES
(32, 'Jonas', 4)


;WITH MaxCapitulos AS
(
    SELECT MAX(Capitulos) AS MaxCap
    FROM   #Livros
),
Capitulos AS
(
    SELECT 1 Cap
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Cap + 1
    FROM Capitulos
    WHERE Cap < (SELECT MaxCap FROM MaxCapitulos) 
)
SELECT Lv.Codigo, Cp.Cap
FROM   #Livros Lv
INNER JOIN Capitulos Cp
    ON Cp.Cap <= Lv.Capitulos
OPTION (maxrecursion 0)
```

Fica aqui uma referência para o habitual [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/142f9/1).

Comment: Muito boa sua solução. Só um detalhe. É interessante usar tabela variável ao invés de temporária nesse caso.

Comment: Obrigado, resolveu o meu problema